# Some features of exported SWT Standalone application not working

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, unix, swt

I've recently developed a SWT Standalone application with eclipse on my Mac OS X. The problem is now that I've finished, I wanted to export my application via the eclipse export to a Runnable Jar file. Everything works fine when I do it on my Mac OS X, but I also want to run the application on Ubuntu and other Unix based distributions. 
So I thought I just import my eclipse project into the eclipse application on the respective OS and export the application again as a Runnable Jar. The problem is now that most of the features of my application don't work anymore ... Suddenly simple things like text boxes aren't displayed anymore and buttons don't work anymore.
The strange thing is when I start the application within my eclipse application everything works fine. I desperately tried to find a way of how to solve this problem, but I couldn't find anything yet. Hope someone can help me out here with this problem ...
Is it just a version problem or do I miss something else?

Here is an example code from one of my jface Dialogs that I can open from within my application:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
// remaining imports omitted

public class ConnectionSettings extends Dialog {
    /**
     * The current status.
     */
    private Text status;

    // Other privates fields omitted.

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) container.getLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 2;

        // other initialisation of labels and text fields omitted

        Group grpStatus = new Group(container, SWT.NONE);
        grpStatus.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        grpStatus.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2,
                1));
        grpStatus.setText("Status");

        // This Text field isn't shown in the exported application
        status = new Text(grpStatus, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.WRAP
                | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        status.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

        // button omitted

        return container;
    }

    // overriding this methods allows you to set the
    // title of the custom dialog
    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Connection Settings");
    }

    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        return new Point(450, 348);
    }
```

That's how it looks like when I start my application within eclipse:
[image: That's how it looks like when I start my application within eclipse:]

That's how it looks like when I start my exported application:
[image: That's how it looks like when I start my exported application:]

As you can see the text field is just not displayed while everything else works fine.

Comment: You'll have to post some example code that shows your problem. It's nearly impossible to tell what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: @Baz Ok I added one example of what isn't working ;)

Comment: Curious. Which SWT version do you use in Eclipse and which SWT version do you bundle with your exported application?

Comment: @tom1991te If I were to guess, you are adding the SWT JARs manually, rather than creating a plugin project. Also, you aren't adding the correct JARs to the build path.

Comment: @GGrec What do you mean with adding the SWT JARs manually ... Here is how my project looks like: http://s8.postimg.org/g8h1je4th/Project_Setup.png

Comment: @Baz How can I find out which SWT version eclipse packages in my executable JAR? I only know that my SWT version within eclipse is: org.eclipse.swt_3.103.1.v20140903-1938.jar
Doesn't eclipse packages exactly the same SWT version when exporting it?

Comment: @tom1991te Are you using deltapack to export the JAR for a different OS? You've said the project was developed and exported on Mac, but tested on Ubuntu. [Have you seen this tutorial?](http://ugosan.org/eclipse-rcp-delta-pack/). That will allow you to export to multiple platforms, SPECIFICALLY.

Comment: @GGrec No I don't use deltapack, but I also don't have a product configuration ... Yes I said it was developed on Mac OS X, but I import the project on my Ubuntu machine and then export it via eclipse ... I was aware that I cannot export it on mac and than run it on Ubuntu, but I thought it should work when I export it directly on Ubuntu ...